# Typescript, ReduxJS Toolkit - Reducer generated by createSlice is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, AnyAction>'

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to typescript and having an issue understanding an error. I'm attempting to use a reducer generated by @reduxjs/toolkit's `createSlice` and feeding that into a function with the following definition:

```
// .d.ts file
export default function persistReducer<S, A extends Action = Action>(
  config: PersistConfig<S>,
  baseReducer: Reducer<S, A>
): Reducer<S & PersistPartial, A>;

// function definition
export default function persistReducer<State: Object, Action: Object>(
  config: PersistConfig,
  baseReducer: (State, Action) => State
): (State, Action) => State & PersistPartial { /* ... */
```

Which is returning the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Reducer<CoreState, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CoreState | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CoreState'.ts(2345)
```

However, it works when I cast the reducer as the `Reducer` type provided by redux/toolkit.

```
// fails
persistReducer( persistConfig, coreReducer )

// succeeds
persistReducer( persistConfig, coreReducer as Reducer)
```

As far as I can tell, the reducer already has that type and I'm not sure why I need to cast the value before sending it along. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my slice definition

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export type User = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  avatar: string,
  token: string
}

export type CoreState {
  isSignedIn: boolean,
  user: User | null
};

const defaultCoreState : CoreState = {
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: null
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'core',
  initialState: defaultCoreState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state: CoreState, action: PayloadAction<User | null>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.isSignedIn = action.payload ? true : false;
    }
  }
});

export const { setUser } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Edit: a reducer created using `combineReducers` triggers the same error, and is alleviated with the same workaround. It seems to me that `persistReducer` function is having trouble inferring the type even though it has imported same `Reducer` type definition from the same library. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the generous help of @phryneas on the Reactiflux discord, the issue has been solved.

```
export default function persistReducer<S, A extends Action = Action>
```

Should become:

```
export default function persistReducer<S, A extends AnyAction>
```

Having seen the word "Action" and "Any" so many times in all the definitions I combed through while debugging this, I missed the difference. `AnyAction` is the correct type.

Comment: having the similar error, sorry, does it mean we must change function definition to `export default function persistReducer<S, A extends AnyAction> or ? Thanks in advance`

Comment: @CiptoHD yes, `A extends AnyAction` is the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack to use if you are trying to upgrade your project but don't want to rewrite everything. Instead of fixing the `persistReducer` in the node module, I've used:

```
const persisted_reducer = persistReducer<any, any>(persist_config, combined_reducers);
```

I faced this issue when I tried to use old-style Redux reducers with Redux toolkit slices.